# Passing parameter from XSLT to template

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I have been trying to pass a parameter from my transform to the xsl file, but when i try to use its value, it always seems to be blank.

My java code:

```
myTransformer.setParameter("show", "all");
```

And my global declaration of the parameter in the xsl file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="show"/>
```

I am trying to test the value in the template like this:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="$show"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($show, ' =? ','all')"/>
```

but "show" is always blank. I have tried putting double and single quotes in the java code for the value "'all'" to avoid being interpreted as an xpath, also tried to use xsl:with-param inside the template, but nothing seems to work...

**edit**
This is a more extended part of my xsl file (carpresentor.xsl):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="show" /> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html><body>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        </body></html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <h1 style="color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;"></h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="$show"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($show, ' =? ','all')"/>
        <table align="center" border="2" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="*[position() = 1]/@*">
                <td><xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(), ' ')"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="*[position() = 1]/*">
                <td><xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(), ' ')"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And a part of my xmltransformer.java (void init and doPost):

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws UnavailableException {
        System.out.println("Init start");

    try {   
        ctx = config.getServletContext(); // we will use the 'contex' below
        absPath = ctx.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/carPresentor.xsl");
        xsltDoc = new SAXSource(new InputSource(absPath));
        tF = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilderFactory fact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        fact.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = fact.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse(absPath);
        System.out.println("Name of document element is " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    } 

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("dopost start");
    System.out.println("Name of document element (at the post) is " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    String color = request.getParameter("color");
    String tablecolor = request.getParameter("table-color"); // edw to request 
    String xml = request.getParameter("show");
    PrintWriter pwr = response.getWriter();
    try {
        DOMSource ds = new DOMSource(doc);
        System.out.println(((Document) ds.getNode()).getDocumentElement().getNodeName() + " " + ((Document) ds.getNode()).getDocumentElement().getNodeValue());
        myTransformer = tF.newTransformer(new DOMSource(doc));
        myTransformer = tF.newTransformer(xsltDoc);
        myTransformer = tF.newTransformer(ds);
        StreamSource xmlSource; 
        xmlSource = new StreamSource(ctx.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/cars.xml"));
        System.out.println("Sending back the xml transformed into html");
        response.setContentType("text/html"); //in order to put in http body
        myTransformer.transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(pwr));
        myTransformer.setParameter("show", "'xml'"); 
        pwr.close();
    }
```

I use DOM & SAX parsers for the transformation. My goal is to use the extra parameter "show" in the xsl file to show differently some xml attributes depending on user input (the html form the java file requests its parameters from).

Comment: The method you are using looks correct - it matches the implementation that I use in my own projects. It would be helpful to have a complete but concise XSL file that demonstrates the problem, as well as a Java method that performs the transformation.

Comment: There's a bug somewhere, but it's not in the bits of code that you've shown us. So as @vallismortis says, put together a complete repro (and say what XSLT processor you are using).

Comment: I updated the post with some more code - hope i chose the correct parts of it...

Comment: I would expect your code to first set the parameter and to then call the `transform` method: ` myTransformer.setParameter("show", "'xml'");        myTransformer.transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(pwr));`.

Comment: This was a bug for sure! So simple! Thank you very much!